# Static background image location in obj-c (similar to background-attachment: fixed)

Tags: ios, objective-c, css

I am trying to create a view that, no matter how it's moved, will keep its background image at the same location.  So, if the view is dragged around, the background stays put, similar to `background-attachment:fixed` in css3.

My problem is that `clipsToBounds = YES` does not appear to work.  The image still takes up the whole screen and does not get clipped to the parent's frame.  Any ideas?

```
@implementation StaticBackgroundView {
    UIImageView *imageView;
}

// Must be init'd from code or won't work
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;

        [self addSubview:imageView];
        [self sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    // Call the parent class to move the view
    [super setFrame:frame];

    // Do your custom code here.
    NSLog(@"Setframe");
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(-1*frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the StaticBackgroundView gets moved - the background image center must also be adjusted.

In the example given below, **updateBackgroundImage** is called every time the StaticBackgroundView gets moved during a PanGesture update.

```
-(void)updateBackgroundImage
{
    imageView.center = CGPointMake(( (imageView.image.size.width*0.5) - self.center.x) + (self.bounds.size.width*0.5)
                               ,     ((imageView.image.size.height*0.5) - self.center.y) + (self.bounds.size.height*0.5));
}
```

If you move the StaticBackgroundView towards to right, the image gets moved towards the left and appears to remain static beneath the StaticBackgroundView.

Example code below which allows you to use your finger to move the StaticBackgroundView about and show a static image beneath:

StaticBackgroundView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface StaticBackgroundView : UIView
-(void)updateBackgroundImage;
@end
```

StaticBackgroundView.m

```
#import "StaticBackgroundView.h"

@implementation StaticBackgroundView {
    UIImageView *imageView;
}

// Must be init'd from code or won't work
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"StaticBackgroundView:initWithFrame");

        if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
            {
                NSLog(@"iPhone5 image");
                imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage-568h"]];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"iPhone4 image");
                imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];
            }
        }
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [self updateBackgroundImage];
        [self addSubview:imageView];
        [self sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)updateBackgroundImage
{
    imageView.center = CGPointMake(( (imageView.image.size.width*0.5) - self.center.x) + (self.bounds.size.width*0.5)
                               ,     ((imageView.image.size.height*0.5) - self.center.y) + (self.bounds.size.height*0.5));
}
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "StaticBackgroundView.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic)  StaticBackgroundView *outletStaticView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.outletStaticView = [[StaticBackgroundView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 120, 150)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.outletStaticView];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];

    [self.outletStaticView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

    if([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {

        CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];

        gestureRecognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(gestureRecognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, gestureRecognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);

        [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

        StaticBackgroundView * theView = (StaticBackgroundView*)gestureRecognizer.view;
        [theView updateBackgroundImage];

    }

}
@end
```

Comment: This is okay if the view I care about is the target of the panning, but what if another view entirely is the cause of the change in location?  Or if the view is animating?

Comment: you there?  any ideas to overcome that issue?

Comment: If the view is animating then you're out of luck. You can only obtain the start and end animation transformation data - not while it's animating

Comment: If another view causes the change, then adjust handlePan accordingly. The translation value of the other view will adjust the static background view.