# User defined Control for Xcode Project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am working on an iPhone app. This app is having many views in which address should show in more than 3 views. Other than creating xib, is there any way to build user defined control like address with events for iPhone in xcode.

Comment: Yes you can create a custom `UIView`in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create subclass of `UIView` to create your own `UIView` control. You could also subclass `UIControl` if you like. Then you should implement the functionality of the control inside the created subclass.

Once you have your own `UIView` subclass ready, you can place it in either Storyboard or Interface Builder and choose the class of the control. Just be careful that if you subclass `UIView`, you also place `UIView` on screen. Or you can place those in code.

More information about subclassing on links below:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-in-ios-5-a-5-star-rating-view
- [Proper practice for subclassing UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978370/proper-practice-for-subclassing-uiview)

There is no other way of defining your own custom control in Xcode, apart from creating .xib.