# Best practice to subclass UIKit classes

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, uikit

I'm using `Swift`, and I find myself having to subclass `UIKit` classes such as `UIView` and `UIButton`. I don't care about setting the frame since I'm using `AutoLayout`, so I don't want/need to use `init(frame: CGRect)`.

```
class customSubclass: UIView {
    var logo: UIImage
    init(logo: UIImage) {
       self.logo = logo

       //compiler yells at me since super.init() isn't called before return from initializer

       //so I end up doing this
       super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
       self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
```

I also don't find it very sexy to set it's frame to `CGRectZero`.

Is there a way to having a custom initializer for a subclass of a UIView or UIButton without explicitly setting it's frame?

**Note**  Every subclass is instantiated in code, so `required init(coder: aDecoder)` is in my code, but isn't actually doing anything.

Thanks!

Comment: IMO it's better practice to not have the view itself set up in a way that it knows that you are going to be sizing it with autolayout.  It should initialize it's frame to a sensible value based on the content you pass it in the initializer.  Maybe origin 0,0 and size equal to logo.size in the case of your example.

Comment: @dan so what would I gain by passing in a valid frame if I'll disregard it anyways? The other thing I can do is create an `init` function that takes in the `frame` as well as other parameters that I need like

    `init( frame: CGRect, logo: UIImage)` 

but then I have to define the frame in the view controller

Comment: Your view shouldn't know that you are going to disregard the frame.  It should set itself up so that it will have a sensible frame even if whatever creates it doesn't give it a new one.

Comment: `init(frame frame: CGRect)` is the designated initializer for UIView. The rules for initialization say you must call it. This is what the compiler is enforcing. Don't blame the compiler, at best, blame UIView. And when you've decided that won't change anything, leave your code as is. Although I would init with a size in case I break the autolayout constraints and can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

During initialization of a subclass, you must call the designated initializer of a superclass. In your case, since you are creating these views programmatically, you must use `super.init(frame: CGRect)`. As you mentioned, it would be useful to implement two designated initializers for your subclass, one of which takes in a `frame:CGRect` argument.

Please see the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978370/proper-practice-for-subclassing-uiview) for a more thorough review.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using autolayout in a storyboard or xib, then just override the `init(coder:)` method so that it calls the superclass's version, and have your convenience initializers pass `CGRectZero` or some other value in.

Comment: I said in my question that I'm instantiating everything in code, so `init(coder:)` is useless. It just has to be there for me to maintain a good relationship with the compiler

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new class and subclassing, you could try using extensions.

```
extension UIView {
    var logo: UIImage = myImage
    func myLogo() {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just adding a function to the UIView class, not returning an instance of the subclass I need