# What is the steps to create a subclass for UIView that adds border?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subclassing

In my current project, I often create a UIView to put a grey rectangle on the view. I usually put white views first on the layout, and then set all of the border in the `viewDidLoad()`. Now I decided that I want to speed things up by writing a subclass that will automatically set the border of the view, and then set all those views to use that subclass. But I don't know where to put this code on the subclass:

```
self.layer.borderWidth = 2;
self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor;
```

Do I put it on `override init()`? Do I need to override every version of `init` for the UIView? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

PS: if there's also any way to make that the border can be immediately shown on the storyboard design time (I think it has something to do with `drawable` but I don't understand at all about it), I'll be very grateful!

**EDIT:**

From the accepted answer, I get this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33721647/3003927 which basically like this:

```
import UIKit

class MyView: UIView {
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      didLoad()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    didLoad()
  }

  convenience init() {
    self.init(frame: CGRectZero)
  }

  func didLoad() {
    //Place your initialization code here
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pretty detailed answer here:

[Proper practice for subclassing UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978370/proper-practice-for-subclassing-uiview)

Basically, you should override:

`init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` and `init(frame: CGRect)` as well as `awakeFromNib()`. Just call another function from there where you set the border.

Comment: Thanks! The answer that really become my solution from your link is this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33721647/3003927 which put a `didLoad()` function call on both init frame and init coder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create subclass of UIView and declare IBInspectable properties as per your needs in this class .

Try below links as example :

http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ibdesignables-in-xcode-6-and-ios-8

Comment: I see, so it's inspectable/designable, not drawable lol. I'm checking it right now. Thanks!