# How to make UIView change color when pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I would like to make a `UIView` highlighted after it's pressed and return to the normal color after release. What is the best practise for doing this?

Comment: Use a `UIButton`.

Answer (score 11):

Subclass the `UIView`:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}
```

Apple about overriding `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`:

> When creating your own subclasses, call super to forward any events
>   that you do not handle yourself. If you override this method without
>   calling super (a common use pattern), you must also override the other
>   methods for handling touch events [i.e. `touchesEnded`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesCancelled`], even if your implementations do
>   nothing.

Further reading:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview

[Proper practice for subclassing UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978370/proper-practice-for-subclassing-uiview)

Answer (score 3):

Very simple example - you can run it in a Playground page:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.backgroundColor = .green
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

In practice, though, you want some additional code to check state, handle `touchesCancelled`, etc.

This is just to get you going - read up on touch events at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview