# change the color of uiview when pressed/released

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Is there a way to change color of the uiview when pressed and released.

I tried it using touchesBegan and touchesEnded by overriding it but it effected the existing functionality. so without effecting the existing functionality can we achieve it ?

Comment: What does this view do? Maybe you should be using a `UIButton` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make uiview change color when pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776551/how-to-make-uiview-change-color-when-pressed)

Comment: Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the view. When touch state is begin set the color and release change to another color when state is released.

Comment: @Sateesh how to detect the state of uiview?

Comment: Like the answer state by @Natarajan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIGestureRecognizer` to detect touch events on your view. Please refer below links for more info.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/433-uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-getting-started
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer

Example:

```
let myView = UIView()
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapEventDetected(gesture:)))
myView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

@objc func tapEventDetected(gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer){

        if gesture.state == .began{

            //Set touch began color
        }

        if gesture.state = .ended{

            //Set touch ended color
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I had tried using the touches began and touches ended method but it had impacted the original functionality

Comment: Okay, So that I recommended you to use UIGestureRecognizer. Please see example code in my edited answer.

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer calls the action after the tap is finished, in iOS 15.