# Why autolayout constraints are not setting properly in willMove(toSuperView) method according to the superview

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a problem to setting the constraints of a custom uiview which is loaded from nib and added as subview to a containerview. I'm trying to add the constraints in the `willMove(toSuperView)` method but it's not working as expected. Where is the most appropriate place to set constraints of a custom `UIView` ?

Heres the code;

```
extension ErrorView {

    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        super.willMove(toSuperview: newSuperview)
        guard let newSuperview = newSuperview else { return }
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        newSuperview.setConstraintHeight(to: self)
        SetConstraintWidth(to: newSuperview)
    }
}
```

the `setConstraintWidth` and `setConstraintHeight` method names are placeholders. You can think as they are methods to setting the constraints.

Comment: are you adding the subclassed `UIView` to container view using code ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I knwo overriding layoutsubviews() will do the work

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    //funky stuff here
}
```

here's a great answer for a similar issue : [Proper practice for subclassing UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978370/proper-practice-for-subclassing-uiview)

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622629-willmove):

> Tells the view that its superview is about to change to the specified superview.

So, that is taking place *before* the view is added to the new view.

Overriding `didAddSubview()` is probably a better place to add your constraints.